# Is it possible to have a dynamic `data_path_template` in Cloud Storage BigQuery Data Transfer Service?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, terraform, google-cloud-storage

I have a Google Storage Bucket that will have timestamped JSONL files uploaded with the following path pattern:

```
<year>/<month>/<day>/<hour>/<id>/<start_minute>:<start_second>-<end_minute>:<end_second>.jsonl
```

So for example:

```
2023/05/19/21/A9887e4d2f6fc1acb01/15:54-16:04.jsonl
```

I would like to load these to BigQuery into an hourly partitioned table.

I'm trying to set up a scheduled Cloud Storage BigQuery Data Transfer Service for this purpose (using Terraform, see below), but a bit stumped how to specify the `data_path_template` so that it would only glob the previous hour's files.

Or maybe it doesn't matter if it's using last modification times (as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-storage-transfer#limitations), relevant paragraph pasted below)?

> Transfers from Cloud Storage set the Write preference parameter to APPEND by default. In this mode, an unmodified file can only be loaded into BigQuery once. If the file's last modification time property is updated, then the file will be reloaded.

I'm a bit worried about the extra scans as the bucket grows, but did I understand right that [BigQuery Data Transfer Service is free from Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#bqdts) anyway? Or would I still need to pay increasing [Operation charges](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#process-pricing) for these scans?

```
resource "google_bigquery_data_transfer_config" "query_config" {
  display_name           = "sensor-data-ingestion"
  location               = var.region
  data_source_id         = "google_cloud_storage"
  schedule               = "every 1 hours from 00:10 to 23:10"
  destination_dataset_id = google_bigquery_dataset.main.dataset_id
  params = {
    data_path_template              = "gs://${google_storage_bucket.sensor-data.name}/*.jsonl"
    destination_table_name_template = "sensor_data_partitioned"
    file_format                     = "JSON"
    write_disposition               = "WRITE_APPEND"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct that the transfer are free of charge as stated at the table, But separate charges may apply to BQ and Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: Right, and while using the file modification filter BQ charges should be fine as each data file will be ingested once, but Cloud Storage charges can apply for the scans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spent way too much time on this, but found out that the answer is yes!

Apparently, there is a templating system for both the bucket URI and the table partition, documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/gcs-transfer-parameters#load_a_snapshot_of_all_data_into_an_ingestion-time_partitioned_table) and it looks like this for Cloud Storage (also available for S3 and Blob Storage):

| Data source | Parameterized URI or data path | Parameterized destination table name | Evaluated URI or data path | Evaluated destination table name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cloud Storage | gs://bucket/events-{run_time|"%Y%m%d"}/*.csv | mytable${run_time|"%Y%m%d"} | gs://bucket/events-20180215/*.csv | mytable$20180215 |

Even better, it supports time and offsetting from transfer run time too! The [parameter format is documented here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/s3-transfer-parameters#param-templating-syntax) while the [date and time parts are documented here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/format-elements#format_elements_date_time), see for example:

| run_time (UTC) | Templated parameter | Output destination table name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-02-15 00:00:00 | mytable | mytable |
| 2018-02-15 00:00:00 | mytable_{run_time|"%Y%m%d"} | mytable_20180215 |
| 2018-02-15 00:00:00 | mytable_{run_time+25h|"%Y%m%d"} | mytable_20180216 |
| 2018-02-15 00:00:00 | mytable_{run_time-1h|"%Y%m%d"} | mytable_20180214 |
| 2018-02-15 00:00:00 | mytable_{run_time+1.5h|"%Y%m%d%H"} or mytable_{run_time+90m|"%Y%m%d%H"} | mytable_2018021501 |
| 2018-02-15 00:00:00 | {run_time+97s|"%Y%m%d"}_mytable_{run_time+97s|"%H%M%S"} | 20180215_mytable_000137 |

So, a working Terraform example would be (note that both " and $ needs escaping):

```
resource "google_bigquery_data_transfer_config" "sensor-data-ingestion" {
  depends_on             = [google_storage_bucket.sensor-data, google_project_iam_member.sensor-data-ingestion-token-creator, google_project_iam_member.sensor-data-ingestion-data-editor, google_bigquery_table.sensor-data-main-partitioned, google_service_account.sensor-data-ingestion-service-account]
  display_name           = "sensor-data-transfer"
  location               = var.region
  data_source_id         = "google_cloud_storage"
  schedule               = "every 1 hours from 00:10 to 23:10"
  destination_dataset_id = google_bigquery_dataset.main.dataset_id
  service_account_name   = google_service_account.sensor-data-ingestion-service-account.email
  params = {
    data_path_template              = "gs://${google_storage_bucket.sensor-data.name}/{run_time-1h|\"%Y%m%d%H\"}*.jsonl"
    destination_table_name_template = "${google_bigquery_table.sensor-data-main-partitioned.table_id}$${run_time-1h|\"%Y%m%d%H\"}"
    file_format                     = "JSON"
    write_disposition               = "APPEND"
  }
}
```

I wasted a couple of days trying to make wildcard globbing work with paths using `/` but had to remove them and use `_` as separator, so eventually settled on file names like `2023060615_A9887e4d2f6fc1acb01_50_51-50_51.jsonl`.